# Best way to communicate time between laravel and vue.js with inertia

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I'm working with laravel inertia and vue js now I'm facing a problem where time transfer between laravel and vue js always convert itself to UTC which not I want.

Example: I'm using `UTC+8` timezone when the created date time response from server side at **10am** but when I inspect on client side it converted to **2am**. Also when I submit a request with field time at **10am** it convert itself to **2am**. Could you help suggest the way to work with that both on server side and client side.

Comment: set your timezone in `config/app.php` -> `'timezone' => 'APP_TIMEZONE=Europe/Berlin',` (example)

Comment: Already add it but it's seem like it doesn't affect the time submit from client and also at client side still see in UTC time.

Comment: did you ever sort out this? Inertia form feature also converts date to UTC when client submit and is giving me a big headache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@TomasLucena I read an article/answer that recommended communicating in UTC and converting it manually based on the client's system time zone, so I have implemented this approach by convert the time from UTC to UTC+8 and save it to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is helpful, but I experienced the same types of problems mentioned in this question and in the comment by Thomas Lucena above.  The date/time kept changing from what was entered with the vue datepicker, due to timezone changes.

This problem was eventually resolved using the vue datepicker 'model-type' setting, and removing timezone and utc settings.  Everything started working correctly after specifying the format as: model-type="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss".  For example:

```
<VueDatePicker id="form.date1 v-model="form.date1" model-type="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
 :enable-time-picker="true" :is24="false" />
```

I also no longer needed to parse the request data with Carbon on the server, because the data is already returned in mysql datetime format.

However, if you're using Laravel data validation, the date format is specified differently than for the vue datepicker.  On the server, use the validation 'date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s'

Anyway, I hope this may be helpful for anyone who runs into this timezone issue using inertia with the vue datepicker